# Make report customer viewed product follow useragent

Tags: magento

I'm trying to make a report about customer viewed product follow useragent but still not yet understand the relationship between tables in magento database diagram clearly. You can see my desire bellow(I'm a new member so still not enough point to post screenshoot):

```
Period          Customername     Productname    Device   Time

Sep 17, 2011    customername1    Iphone4        Wap     Sep 17, 2011 12:17:28 PM
                customername1    Iphone4        Web     Sep 17, 2011 2:03:35 PM
```

Table "report_event" and related tables are used to get "customer name" and "product name". And now, I want to know each of product view request times from which useragent. I also found the attribute "http_user_agent" in table "log_visitor_info" but don't know whether it's useful

Can I make this report? Please give me your ideas about that

Answer (score 0):

yes `log_visitor_info` table has all the details of visitors, we can track that user by the way.